# Full day Event (with out any End date)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say  :
There is a `Full day Event` (with out any End date) and Event Start  at 08/02/2020 
and i want when its come day after Event : 09/02/2020 
 It give me an alert The event has ended.

Can anyone please help me :) Thanks :)

JavaScript:

```
function FullDayEvent(EndDate, StartDate) {
    if (EndDate === null) {

        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        Today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

        var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
        var results = pattern.exec(StartDate);
        var dtStart = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
        var FullDayEvent = dtStart.getDate() + "/" + (dtStart.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dtStart.getFullYear();

        var ResultDate = today (Here is my problem, what operators should i used  when its come day after Event ??) FullDayEvent ? "The event has ended" : "The event has not ended yet";
        alert(ResultDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `date` in javascript, it is actually the number of milliseconds since 01/01/1970. You can thus compare those number of milliseconds.

As those are numbers you may simply use the *greater than* `>` and *lower than* `<` operator

```js
function isAfterEvent(eventDate) {
  const today = new Date();
  const hasEventEnded = today > eventDate;
  return "Event of " + eventDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10) + " has ended => " + (hasEventEnded ? "YES" : "NO");
}

const eventA = new Date("2019-07-26");
const eventB = new Date("2059-02-25");

console.log(isAfterEvent(eventA));
console.log(isAfterEvent(eventB));
```